# File content to byte array?

Tags: java, file, arrays

I'd like to create some various files (txt, pdf, xml, html) and I'd like to store them as byte array.

Is there any method that I don't create these files, but I 'fill' its text contents (String) into byte arrays?

Now I create the file, convert it to byte array and delete it.

It is so long, and I'd like to simplify this process.
I don't want to create the file, I want store the file content immediately into byte array.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: Store what content? What's creating the file? This question is too vague at the moment.

Comment: Could you clarify the end purpose of that? You might not be able to store entire files into memory

Comment: I have a database where I store txt, xml, html and pdf files in BLOB (byte array format). Now I create the txt, xml, html, pdf files, convert them to byte arrays, store them into the database, and delete them. I'd like to skip file creating and file deleting process.

Comment: When you say "I create the txt, xml, html, pdf files", what do you mean by that?

Comment: It is a Java program, that calculates various results and store them in various file formats. It is an Eclipse project and there is a temp folder in the project, and the program creates these files in this temp folder. So these files are in my disk drive. I have a PostgreSQL database, and after the program created the files, stores them in this database, and finally deletes them.

Comment: for example, the txt and html files are created by FileWriter.

Comment: Then I suggest using `OutputStreamWriter` writing to `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Answer (score 0):

Current code:

```
Writer w = new FileWriter( ... );
// writing operations, closing the writer
```

New code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(baos, "UTF-8");
// writing operations, closing the writer

byte [] file = baos.toByteArray();  // Your file
```